# Wordpress update_user_meta is not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to build a function for my wordpress page which behaves as follows:

1. If a specific user meta value exists, it is printed
2. If it doesn't exist, an input field allows the user to add it

My code is posted below, when I try to execute it a few weird things happen:

1. When the user submits the form, the page reloads but the input field is still there, i.e. the new meta value isn't printed
2. If I manually refresh the page the meta value is now printed (and also exists in the database)
3. If I manually refresh again the input field returns again (and the meta value is deleted from the database)

So for some reason resubmitting the page deletes the meta value? What have I done wrong?

```
<?php 

$custom_value = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'custom_value', true );

if ( $custom_value ) { 
   echo $custom_value;
} else { ?>
   <form action="" method="post" style="display: flex;">
      <input type="text" name="c_val" id="c_val" />
      <button type="submit" value="">Add</button>
   </form>
   <?php 
      if ( isset( $_POST['c_val'] ) ) {
         $c_val = $_POST['c_val'];
         update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'custom_value', $c_val );
      }
} 

?>
```

Comment: _"the page reloads but the input field is still there, i.e. the new meta value isn't printed"_ - since you are _reading_ the current value, before you even update the field, this should not be surprising. PHP is not a time machine ... Put your if condition that checks for $_POST['c_val'] and the update_user_meta wrapped within it, at the beginning of your script, _before_ you read the current value from the database.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the first issue with the value not being shown after submission. However when I manually refresh the page, the value disappears again...

Comment: That sounds more like some sort of caching issue.

Answer (score 0):

When your user clicks submit on your form, their browser POSTs to your page. That means WordPress's code to render the page, code that includes your example code, runs again from scratch, but this time with values in the `$_POST` array.

So your logic to determine whether your form has been posted needs to check that array *before* you retrieve the meta value.

```php
<?php 
/* did the user post a new custom value ? */
if ( isset( $_POST['c_val'] ) {
  $custom_value = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['c_val'] );
  update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'custom_value', $custom_value );
} else {
  $custom_value = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'custom_value', true );
}
if ( $custom_value ) { 
   /* if we have a custom value, use it. */
   echo esc_html($custom_value);
} else { ?>
   <form action="" method="post" style="display: flex;">
      <input type="text" name="c_val" id="c_val" />
      <button type="submit" value="">Add</button>
   </form>
}
?>

I added some code to clean up the text coming in from the user.
```

Comment: Thanks - this solution solves isses nbr 1 and 2, however nbr 3 still exists, meaning that as soon as I leave or refresh the page, the meta data entry is for some reason deleted :(

Comment: SOLVED - there was interference caused by some other code further down the document.